# Set Mission Control keyboard shortcuts via cmdline

Tags: command-line, mission-control

Is there a way I can set my keyboard shortcuts for Mission Control from the cmdline / programmatically without having to use a mouse?

I have changed the keyboard shortcuts such that it behaves similar to what I had setup on Gnome / GDM.

switch to workspace left

ctrl+alt+left

switch to workspace right

ctrl+alt+right

switch to specific workspace

Apple / Windows + (n)

Comment: Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344494/how-to-disable-default-mission-control-shortcuts-in-terminal or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201816/how-do-i-change-mission-control-shortcuts-from-the-command-line?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I came across that before, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: …in what way? [Not that it's something I've ever done myself, for me as one user with only 4 Macs, I just do it though the GUI, or clone/migrate drives to new Macs.]

Comment: I'm not seeing that domain oddly enough so I cannot read or write to that?

Comment: Can't find the domain, or the domain pair? The pair may not exist, `defaults write` will create it if it doesn't. It will then exist until specifically removed with `defaults delete`. Many defaults don't exist until told, then they override behaviour that may be specified elsewhere, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459821/85275 for an example. tbh, I've never tried playing in hot keys, so I don't know specifically how it functions.